# Sikulix wait until image not appear anymore i.e page still loading

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-x

I am a new Sikulix user. I have learned how to wait until image appears on screen. But the issue is how to wait until an image is not visible any more. In below code when "nextbutton.jpg" is clicked a loading message appears "progress..." I want Sikulix to only progress when this message is not visible on the screen.

```
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    rightClick("1666114968076.png")
    wait("rightclick2.jpg")
    click("savecsv2.jpg")
    wait("nameandsavefile.jpg")
    click("clickok.jpg")
    click("nextbutton.jpg")
    wait(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (pseudocode):

```
while(True):

 if exists("in progress...:):
     wait(waitTime)

 else:
     break
```